# date time condition in razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, foreach

How to set a condition to say if a data in a table is less than 5 days ago and then display a users information.

Below I can say less than date now.

```
  @foreach (var item in Model)
 {
    if(item.RegisteredAt < DateTime.Now )
   {
   }
 }
```

Comment: You shouldn't be doing any filtering in your view. Your `item` list should only contain the data that you want to display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the difference between two dates as a [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/269ew577.aspx) and use [TotalDays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totaldays.aspx) property.

```
(DateTime.Now - item.RegisteredAt).TotalDays < 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in a negative number to the `AddDays` function.

```
if(item.RegisteredAt < DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5)) {
```

If you wanted to ignore the time portion then you should compare them off the Date property.

```
if(item.RegisteredAt.Date < DateTime.Today.AddDays(-5)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(item.RegisteredAt.Substract(DateTime.Now).Days.ToString().AsInt() < 5)
{
    @* your expected code *@
}
```